# How to share class files between visual c# express and web dev express?

Tags: c#

What if I want to make an application which supports both winform and webform, how do I setup the project files in visual studio or vstudio express ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the express versions, I would create a common class library then reference it in both Visual C# Express's and Visual Web Dev Express's projects. There is no real concept of a solution in the Express editions.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "no concept of a solution". C# Exopress will create and use solutions just fine. I don't have WebDev Express, maybe it uses the "Web Site" (vs Web Proj) approach. WebSite doesn't use Solution or Project files.